# Sprint running record with non-null initial speed (100 m)

Tags: records, running

The 100 m sprint competition starts from standing still. I was wondering, are there records of people running 100 m with starting speed different from zero?

I would imagine sprinters might be able to do it faster than in the race starting from 0 speed if the 100 m are counted from somewhere after that.

Comment: The 200m sprint is run by the same athletes (or at least, there is significant overlap). Comparing records of the same athlete running the two distances, subtracting the 100m time from the 200m time is exactly the "non-null start speed" time for the second 100m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the 2009 Great City Games in Manchester, England, Usain Bolt won the 150m event in a time of 14.35s, which remains the world best for that event. [Bolt ran the final 100m in a time of 8.70s](https://www.givemesport.com/87992994-usain-bolts-2009-150m-race-is-the-fastest-race-in-history), an average speed of 25.71mph, which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt#Personal_bests) claims without citation to be:

> the fastest ever recorded time over a 100 m distance

[This source](http://www.alltime-athletics.com/m4x100ok.htm) found by @ImClarky lists Bolt as having run 100m in 8.69s during Jamaica's 4x100m relay victory at the 2013 World Championships in Moscow, but I'm unsure of its accuracy and can't find any corroborating sources.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anyone keeps official records for this, but you can guesstimate something from the 4×100m relay, which includes three flying start legs:

- Start with the [men's 4×100m world record of 36.84s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_%C3%97_100_metres_relay#Men_2)
- Subtract (say) 9.90s as the typical time for the "standing" start first leg = 26.94s
- Divide by 3 = 8.98s

which is significantly shorter than the [men's 100m world record of 9.58s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_metres#All-time_top_25_men).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the validity/accuracy - but [this site](http://www.alltime-athletics.com/m4x100ok.htm) lists the fastest 4x100m times by a men's team, and in some instances shows the split times - the fastest time I have found is a 8.13 by Canada's Aaron Brown in 2017 - though how a split is calculated, I'm not sure

Comment: @ImClarky I suspect that's a typo and is supposed to say 9.13. If you add up the four split times of that run, they come to 37.54 instead of the actual recorded time of 38.59.

Comment: But even ignoring that one, it's a useful site and the splits for Jamaica's world record are pretty close to my estimate. That "Usain Bolt" guy seems pretty quick ;)